# PWM controller IC selection

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, boost, pid-controller, tl494

I am working on a boost converter with analogue PI control. I want to make the PI controller using a separate Op-amp IC and giving its output to the PWM controller to generate proportional PWM signal. I also thought of using TL494 and giving PI controller's output directly to its feedback pin but I am not sure whether this method will work or not. As in TL494, I am not using the internal opamps, it's wastage so is there an IC without any internal opamp?

Please suggest me a PWM controller IC that fulfils the need, I will be using a separate gate driver to drive the MOSFET.

Comment: Uc384x family? They have one opamp, but usually input is not used/tied to ground. Also, to obtain only voltage mode - ramp compensation on isense input is required

Comment: [LT6992](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC6992-1-6992-2-6992-3-6992-4.pdf)

Comment: @Andyaka Can I use it with Gate driver to drive a high power mosfet?

Comment: Yes, you can. I've used the LT6992 in the past with a high power buck converter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-)